# Javascript to show the date when the file is generated

Tags: javascript

I have a script that generates an html file. I need a JavaScript to generate the date when this file is generated. I have my html template in Kompozer.

This is what I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 var d=new Date();

 var weekday=new Array

 ("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday");

 var monthname=new Array("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","A ug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec");

 document.write(weekday[d.getDay()] + " ");

 document.write(d.getDate() + ". ");

 document.write(monthname[d.getMonth()] + " ");

 document.write(d.getFullYear());</script>
```

The error is that this javascript generates todays date, not the date the html is generated.

Thank you

Comment: It would be more reliable to have the script that generates the HTML file put the date into it at the time.

Comment: JavaScript does not know the date the HTML was generated. Typically you insert that with server side technologies like PHP, Java, .NET

Comment: what do you mean? Do you have any examples?

Comment: But I have a small script in python and I am not using a server...how can I do this without a server?

Comment: They mean that you can't do it in JavaScript. You'll have to do it in Python when you generate the page.

Comment: I have the template in KompoZer because I need really specific fields... so in one of the fields I need to send a JavaScript that get the date where the html is created...

Comment: Basically in Python I just read the html in a string... and post it. I tried to get the date in the string and add it to the html with {date} but it didn't work... do you guys have any example?

Answer (score 0):

No Way. Javascript will always generate today's date when executed with new Date(); - sorry but you have to insert it via server side code (or however the html file is generated)

Comment: Thank you guys, anyone have any example with python?.